# Como faço outros efeitos do JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consegui fazer esses efeitos `fadeIn()` e `fadeOut()`, mas gostaria de saber como faço o outros efeitos como o `pop`.

Usei este sistema:

```
$(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#menu").fadeIn();
    $("#menu ul li a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        link = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut( function(){
            window.location = link;
        });        
    });
});
```

Comment: Detalhe melhor sua dúvida.

Comment: concegui fazer o efeito com fadeIn e fadeOut, mas existe outros efeitos?

Answer (score 3):

Na [documentação do JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) você tem a lista completa dos [efeitos](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) da própria biblioteca.

Os principais são:

- [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)
- [`.fadeIn()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)
- [`.fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)
- [`.fadeToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)
- [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/)
- [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [`.sildeUp()`](https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)e suas variações

Entre outros.

Esse efeitos fazem parte do próprio JQuery. Você tem acesso a eles pelo próprio link da biblioteca.

Entretanto existe a coleção [**Jquery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/), com inúmeros [efeitos e funcionalidades](https://jqueryui.com/effect/) a mais. Para ter acesso a essas funcionalidades baixa ter acesso ao link [dessa coleção](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js). Abaixo segue algumas demonstrações destes efeitos. O código foi tirado do próprio site.

```js
  $(function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
      // get effect type from
      var selectedEffect = $( "#effectTypes" ).val();
 
      // most effect types need no options passed by default
      var options = {};
      // some effects have required parameters
      if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
        options = { percent: 0 };
      } else if ( selectedEffect === "transfer" ) {
        options = { to: "#button", className: "ui-effects-transfer" };
      } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
        options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
      }
 
      // run the effect
      $( "#effect" ).effect( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
    };
 
    // callback function to bring a hidden box back
    function callback() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#effect" ).removeAttr( "style" ).hide().fadeIn();
      }, 1000 );
    };
 
    // set effect from select menu value
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      runEffect();
      return false;
    });
  });
```

```css
    .toggler { width: 500px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
    #button { padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
    #effect { width: 240px; height: 135px; padding: 0.4em; position: relative; }
    #effect h3 { margin: 0; padding: 0.4em; text-align: center; }
    .ui-effects-transfer { border: 2px dotted gray; }
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggler">
  <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Effect</h3>
    <p>
      Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
 
<select name="effects" id="effectTypes">
  <option value="blind">Blind</option>
  <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
  <option value="clip">Clip</option>
  <option value="drop">Drop</option>
  <option value="explode">Explode</option>
  <option value="fade">Fade</option>
  <option value="fold">Fold</option>
  <option value="highlight">Highlight</option>
  <option value="puff">Puff</option>
  <option value="pulsate">Pulsate</option>
  <option value="scale">Scale</option>
  <option value="shake">Shake</option>
  <option value="size">Size</option>
  <option value="slide">Slide</option>
  <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
</select>
 
<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</button>
```

Comment: Bom uso do Stack Snippet ;) +1

Comment: Obrigado, @GuilhermeNascimento.. rsrs Sua resposta foi ótima +1.

Answer (score 2):

O jQuery só tem dois efeitos por padrão, no entanto usado o jquery-ui é possivel adicionar uma série de efeitos como:

`Blind`, `Bounce`, `Clip`, `Drop`, `Explode`, `Fade`, `Fold`, `Highlight`, `Puff`, `Pulsate`, `Scale`, `Shake`, `Size`, `Slide` e `Transfer`

No entanto adicionar um biblioteca inteira apenas para usar parte dele talvez seja desnecessário.

O jQuery é um framework extensível ou seja suporta adicionar funcionalidades aos eventos existentes, por exemplo:

```
$.fx.step['size'] = function(fx)
{
   if ( !fx._sizeInit )
   {
      var $el = $(fx.elem),
          c = fx.end.center || {top: 0, left: 0};

      fx.start = $el.offset();
      $.extend(fx.start, {width: $el.width(), height: $el.height()});

      fx._sizer = {};

      fx._sizer.topDelta = c.top - (c.top * fx.end.height / fx.start.height);
      fx._sizer.leftDelta = c.left - (c.left * fx.end.width / fx.start.width);
      fx._sizer.widthDelta = fx.end.width - fx.start.width;
      fx._sizer.heightDelta = fx.end.height - fx.start.height;

      fx._sizeInit = true;
   }

   fx.elem.style.top = fx.start.top + Math.floor(fx._sizer.topDelta * fx.pos) + 'px';
   fx.elem.style.left = fx.start.left + Math.floor(fx._sizer.leftDelta * fx.pos) + 'px';
   fx.elem.style.width = fx.start.width + Math.floor(fx._sizer.widthDelta * fx.pos) + 'px';
   fx.elem.style.height = fx.start.height + Math.floor(fx._sizer.heightDelta * fx.pos) + 'px';

};
```

O uso seria:

```
$('myDiv')
    .animate({
          size: {
                 center: {top: 0, left: 30}, 
                 height: 100, 
                 width: 200
                }
       }, 'slow');
```

<sup>Fonte: http://www.benknowscode.com/2012/09/extending-jquery-animate-beyond-basic_6504.html</sup>

Veja uma biblioteca https://github.com/benignware/jquery.fx-transition que suporta vários efeitos como:

- swing, linear, ease, easeIn, easeInQuad, easeInCubic, easeInQuart, easeInQuint, easeInSine, easeInExpo, easeInCirc, easeInBack, easeOut, easeOutQuad, easeOutCubic, easeOutQuart, easeOutQuint, easeOutSine, easeOutExpo, easeOutCirc, easeOutBack, easeInOut, easeInOutQuad, easeInOutCubic, easeInOutQuart, easeInOutQuint, easeInOutSine, easeInOutExpo, easeInOutCirc, easeInOutBack

Pegue o arquivo https://github.com/benignware/jquery.fx-transition/blob/master/dist/jquery.fx-transition.min.js (pesa em média ~7kb bem mais leve que o jquery-ui) e junto ao jquery, assim:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Exemplo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../dist/jquery.fx-transition.js"></script>

  </head>
```